# are asynchronous tasks on main thread same as synchronous tasks?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I know the difference between the two kinds.

For async tasks, next task will run after the current one began, which means tasks will be dispatched to multiple threads if there are threads available.
For sync tasks, next task will run after the current one finished.

**How could main thread run async tasks since it only has one thread?**

It's confusing to me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this is really explain full https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SrWWLx5wOEU

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your definitions of asynchronous and synchronous aren't quite right.

In Grand Central Dispatch you consider *queues*, not *threads*.  A queue is either a serial dispatch queue or a concurrent dispatch queue.

A serial dispatch queue can run one task at a time and tasks are dispatched one after the other (serially).

A concurrent dispatch queue can run several tasks simultaneously on multiple threads.

Tasks execute on threads and Grand Central Dispatch takes care of assigning tasks to threads for you.

The main queue is a special serial dispatch queue that only assigns tasks to the main thread.  Other queues can assign tasks to any available thread, including the main thread.

Now, for synchronous versus asynchronous dispatch, the difference is whether the dispatch blocks the current thread until the dispatched task is complete (synchronous) or queues the task without blocking the current thread (asynchronous).

When you dispatch asynchronously onto the main queue, you are providing a unit of work that Grand Central Dispatch will assign to the main thread at some future point, but your code continues executing without waiting for that dispatched item to complete.

You can dispatch asynchronous tasks to the main queue while running on the main queue quite happily, since the dispatched task will execute later, when the main queue is ready for a task.

What you can't do is dispatch *synchronously* onto the main queue *from* the main queue (or more generally, dispatch synchronously onto any serial dispatch queue from that same queue) since you will create a deadlock.

Dispatching synchronously blocks the current thread/queue until the dispatched item is complete.  On a serial dispatch queue the dispatched item can't execute since the dispatching queue is blocked.

Comment: "Other queues can assign tasks to any available thread, including the main thread." This isn't correct (other than serial dispatch *from* the main thread). Dispatching to background queues is often a means of getting long-running tasks off of the main thread. If one of those queues could run such a task on the main thread, it would lock up the UI. Otherwise, good answer. +1

Comment: "Except for the dispatch queue representing your app's main thread, the system makes no guarantees about which thread it uses to execute a task.". It is possible for a queue other than the main queue to make use of the main thread,  it only for work items dispatched asynchronously. Using the main queue guarantees that the block will use the main thread.

Comment: Err, I meant "*synchronous* dispatch from the main thread" (not serial) in my earlier comment. But, really, that's the only way for another queue to use the main thread. It would break everything if other queues could use the main thread for either dispatch from another thread or asynchronous dispatch from the main thread.

Answer (score 4):

> For async tasks, next task will run after the current one began, which means tasks will be dispatched to multiple threads if there are threads available.

Not quite. To dispatch asynchronously only means that the current thread will *not* wait for the dispatched code to finish. It has absolutely nothing to do with whether that destination queue is serial or concurrent.

> For sync tasks, next task will run after the current one finished.

Again, not quite. To dispatch synchronously only means that the current thread *will* wait for the dispatched code to finish execution.

Whether the dispatched code runs concurrently with respect to other items previously dispatched to that queue is dictated by the queue type (i.e. serial or concurrent), not whether we dispatched synchronously or asynchronously.

> How could main thread run async tasks since it only has one thread?

As is likely obvious now, the “asynchronous” vs “synchronous” is not a characteristic of the task being dispatched, but rather only dictates whether the thread from which you are dispatching should wait or not.

So, consider some code that dispatches code asynchronously back to the main thread:

```
let task = URLSession.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, _ in
    let results = ...                 // on `URLSession` background serial queue, only populate local variables
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.objects = results        // dispatch model updates back to main queue
        self.tableView.reloadData()   // also update UI from main queue
    }
}
task.resume()
```

In the above example, we’re dispatching the model and UI updates to the main queue because we’re on the `URLSession` background queue (which happens to be a serial queue, too). And we dispatch it asynchronously because there is no reason for the serial queue of the `URLSession` to wait for the dispatched code to finish. We *could* have dispatched it synchronously, but why would we bother blocking the `URLSession` queue, even if only for a few extra milliseconds.